# Почему при возврате указателя на массив указателей из DLL теряются значения массивов?

Tags: c++

В DLL файле, вызываемым процессом, происходят расчеты и записываются в массивы. На эти массивы я создаю указатель

```
float* pointer[] = { arr1,arr2, &k };
```

После этого я создаю указатель на массив указателей и возвращаю его.

```
float** result= new float*;
result = pointer;
return result;
```

Но при выводе данных из возвращенного процесса где-то после 200 элемента(всего 370) начинаются рандомные числа вроде
254888855952827154321376406405120,000000,
-107374176,000000,
649206180215658893662736663942529024,000000.

Вывожу так

```
while (i < k) {
        printf("X = %f         Y = %f\n", result[0][i], result[1][i]);
        i++;
    }
```

Если сделать тоже самое внутри DLL, то все выводится нормально. Из-за чего это происходит?

Код из DLL

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) float arr1[1000] = { 0 };
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) float arr2[1000] = { 0 };
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) float a=0;
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) float r = 0;
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)  float ** Calc(float a,float r)
{
    int i = 0;
    float h = M_PI / 180, x, y;
    float f = -3;
    while (f <= 3) {
        x = a + r * cos(f);
        y = a * sin(f) / cos(f) + r * sin(f);
        arr1[i] = x;
        arr2[i] = y;
        i++;
        f += h;
    }
    float k = (float)i;
    float* pointer[] = { arrX,arrY, &k };
    float** result = new float*;
    result = pointer;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Неизвестно, как вы их создаете etc etc...

Comment: @Harry Добавил код из функции и обьявление переменных в вопрос

Comment: Итак, у вас локальный массив `pointer`, в котором один элемент - указатель на локальную же переменную... Что, само собой, ведет к неопределенному поведению - после выхода из функции никакого `pointer` больше не существует. И вы возвращаете из функции указатель на этот несуществующий массив. Кстати, а к чему эти танцы с бубном - `float** result = new float*;` - которые только приводят к утечке памяти и ничего более?

Comment: @Harry Как я понял, при таком обьявлении указатель не удалится после выхода из функции.

Comment: При каком? Вы присвоили переменной указатель на выделенную память, потом переприсвоили, потеряв прежнее значение (вот и утечка памяти), и что? Да, выделенная память не удалится при выходе - более того, теперь она не удалится никогда - потому что ее адрес вы перезаписали и больше не знаете, но какое это имеет отношение к вашему `pointer`?..

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, обьявил все глобально и данные вывелись нормально. Можете написать это же в ответ, что бы я отметил его как принятый?

Comment: Да не стоит оно того :)

Comment: @Alexey Harry не может написать это в ответ, потому что "обьявил все глобально" - это ужасно.

Comment: @Igor А причем тут "Обьявил все глобально"? Я имел ввиду его подробное описание причины, по которой не работает, 3 коммент по счету